# How to use the pretrained transformer model ("en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg") in SpaCy?

Tags: python, spacy, transformer-model

I was wondering, how I could use the pretrained transformer model `en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg` from spacy for future NLP tasks (NER, POS, etc.). The documentation states, that the module can only be used for the following pipeline preprocessing modules (https://spacy.io/models/en#en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg):

- sentencizer
- trf_wordpiecer
- trf_tok2vec

Can anyone explain to me, what these components are doing and in which tasks they can be used? Or does anyone know a good sources to read about it?

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg")
>>> nlp.pipe_names
[sentencizer, trf_wordpiecer, trf_tok2vec]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**trf_wordpiecer component**

- accessible via `doc._.trf_alignment`
- performs the model’s wordpiece pre-processing

Quote from the [docs](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers#tokenization-alignment):

> Wordpiece is convenient for training neural networks, but it doesn't
> produce segmentations that match up to any linguistic notion of a
> "word". Most rare words will map to multiple wordpiece tokens, and
> occasionally the alignment will be many-to-many.

**trf_tok2vec component**

- accessible via `doc._.trf_last_hidden_state`
- stores the raw outputs of the transformer: one tensor with one row per wordpiece token
- however, what you probably want are the token-aligned features in `doc.tensor`.

See also this [blog article](https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-transformers) introducing spacy's transformer integration.

Answer (score 1):

The offical documentation explains, that you can use the BERT spacy model `en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg` model to get word embeddings for sentence tokens.

> https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-transformers

Install the spacy BERT model and `spacy-transformers` module:

```sh
pip install spacy-transformers
python -m spacy download en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg
```

Below is a slightly adapted example from the official documentation:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg")
doc = nlp("Apple shares rose on the news. Apple pie is delicious.")

# doc[0] accesses the emmbedding of the first token = 'Apple'
print(doc[0])  # Apple

# doc[7] accesses the emmbedding of the 8th token = 'Apple'
print(doc[7])  # Apple

# they are not the same, because the embedding are context sentitive (check with cosine similarity)    
print(doc[0].similarity(doc[7])) # 0.43365735

# get the shape of the last hidden layer
print(doc._.trf_last_hidden_state.shape)  # (16, 768)

# get the word embeddings for all tokens
print(doc._.trf_last_hidden_state)
```

> [[ 0.34356186 -0.23586863 -0.06684081 ... -0.17081839  0.60623395
> 0.15930347]  [ 0.65008235  0.01991967 -0.11502014 ... -0.5832436  -0.02782568   -0.4122076 ]  [ 1.499611    0.02532474  0.23262465 ... -0.3212682   0.27605072
> 0.18531999]  ...  [ 0.24741858  0.00736329 -0.28011537 ... -0.1693347  -0.20065884   -0.6950048 ]  [ 0.2859776   0.00303659 -0.37783793 ...  0.37828052  0.041728   -0.5648101 ]  [ 0.7320844   0.11067941 -0.04100507 ...  0.25042596 -0.21909392   -0.31274694]]

The word embeddings could be used in further downstream NLP/machine learning task.

Answer (score 0):

SpaCy's [**Language Processing Pipelines**](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) should guide you towards the information you're looking for.

[**Sentencizer**](https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer):
A simple pipeline component, to allow custom sentence boundary detection logic that doesn’t require the dependency parse. By default, sentence segmentation is performed by the `DependencyParser`, so the `Sentencizer` lets you implement a simpler, rule-based strategy that doesn’t require a statistical model to be loaded. The component is also available via the string name `"sentencizer"`. After initialization, it is typically added to the processing pipeline using `nlp.add_pipe`.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was rather thinking about the other two components, also how they can be used in other NLP tasks. But I will propably will have to read up on it.